# Will a faster internet connection improve my actual speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I get 300 megabits/s on my ethernet. My Wi-Fi is quite poor. I only get about 15 megabits/s when I am far from the router. My question is: if I upgrade to 500 or 1000 megabit/s internet, will my wireless connection improve? I understand that my wired will obviously go up accordingly but will the wireless?

Another question is if this is normal? My last wifi pod (out of 4) is 2 stories away from the router and on the other side of the house. (Maybe 80ft)

Thanks in advance.

*Here is the setup in case you need to know.

Router/Modem Combo => Plume Extenders (4) => Wireless device (Connected to the last pod)

Comment: No, your internet will not improve because your wifi is cutting it. You should get a better wifi setup. 15 megabits/s is really on the low side. 120mbit or higher is definitely possible with wifi 5 and the right equippment and distance

Comment: With each repeater in the wifi chain, you are going to degrade the total throughput available to the end user. Best way to improve wifi performance is to hard wire access points back to router/switch. If this isn't an option, you are left to try your repeaters in different locations of the house with some trial and error and/or a wifi signal analyzer app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I upgrade to 500 or 1000 Mbps Internet, will my wireless connection improve?

No, your WiFi is currently the bottleneck on your speed, not your internet connection itself. You could have 10Gbps internet and if the WiFi signal or router is bad, you will only be able to use as much bandwidth as your WiFi can provide, which it sounds like you are currently saturating.

> Is this normal?

Yes, to a degree. WiFi is unreliable for anything other than video streaming (buffering) and web browsing. It was designed for convenience, not performance. In my experience, you will be lucky to get more than 25 Mbps more than 50ft away from a router/access point, maybe less through walls (depending on what the walls are made of). While WiFi has come a long way, a wire will beat wireless in every measurable metric.

Range extenders that are not wired-in, while they increase signal strength, will oftentimes reduce the overall available bandwidth.